# Drupal: passing arguments to drupal_get_form form function

Tags: drupal, forms, drupal-6, arguments, drupal-modules

Is there any way to pass arguments into a function called via `drupal_get_form` function something like `drupal_get_form('form_func', array('arg1' => 1, ...));`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's there in the documentation:

"... Any additional arguments are passed on to the functions called by drupal_get_form(), including the unique form constructor function. For example, the node_edit form requires that a node object be passed in here when it is called."

http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_get_form/6

:)